# Query multiple objects from an array based on varying parameters and return a total from all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a job tracker application and I want to be able to query jobs from an array (database/JSON based) and add their 'pay' together. This is what I have tried.

```
var arr = [
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Louis', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Mike', dateDay: 13, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Greg', dateDay: 14, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 35 },
  { name: 'Josh', dateDay: 15, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 15 },
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Dan', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 30 }
];

function filter(arr, criterias) {
  let total = 0;
  criterias.forEach(criteria => {
    arr.filter(function(obj) {
      Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
        if (obj[c] === criteria[c]) {
          total = total + obj.pay;
        }
      });
    });
  });
   return total;
}

filter(arr, [{ dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020 }, { dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 2, dateYear: 2020 }]);
```

This returns 250 when it SHOULD return 50. Right now the month and year parameters are effectively ignored. What change do I need to make to the function in order for this to work like I need it to?, which is to make sure the job satisfies every parameter in each passed 'criteria'.

Appreciate any help. Been struggling with this for a couple days now.

Comment: Worth reading how `every` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: @Daniel - The result should be `20` and not `50`.

Comment: Did you mean `Dan`'s `dateMonth` to be `2`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Yes. Either `dan's` datemonth should be `2` or the object passed in `criterias` datemonth should be `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you are not returning any boolean value from callback to "every" function, so by default only first key that is dateDay will be checked against stops checking rest.  "filter" callback also doesn't return any boolean.

also, only name ="steve" is matching one of given criteria. 
so my assumption is output should be 20.
if that's the case use following code.

```
var arr = [
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Louis', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Mike', dateDay: 13, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Greg', dateDay: 14, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 35 },
  { name: 'Josh', dateDay: 15, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 15 },
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Dan', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 30 }
];

function filter(arr, criterias) {
  let total = 0;
  criterias.forEach(criteria => {
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
      let criteriaMet = Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
        if (obj[c] === criteria[c]) {
          return true;
        }
      }); if(criteriaMet){total += obj.pay}
    });
  });
   return total;
}

filter(arr, [{ dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020 }, { dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 2, dateYear: 2020 }])
```

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what I need it to! Such a simple fix, I understand why it works now.

Answer (score 0):

First `filter` the objects, that are present in `criterias` array and then use `reduce` to `sum` the `pay` amount.

```js
var arr = [
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Louis', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Mike', dateDay: 13, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Greg', dateDay: 14, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 35 },
  { name: 'Josh', dateDay: 15, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 15 },
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Dan', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 30 }
];

function filter(arr, criteria) {
  return arr
    .filter(({dateYear, dateMonth, dateDay}) => criteria
    .some(({dateDay: criDay, dateMonth: criMon, dateYear: criYear}) => (dateDay == criDay && dateMonth == criMon && dateYear == criYear)))
    .reduce((a, {pay}) => a+ pay, 0);
}

console.log(filter(arr, [{ dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020 }, { dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020 }]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test the result of every. Then add the result to the total. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr0j8bvx/) illustrating that.

```
var arr = [
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Louis', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 100 },
  { name: 'Mike', dateDay: 13, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Greg', dateDay: 14, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 35 },
  { name: 'Josh', dateDay: 15, dateMonth: 12, dateYear: 2019, pay: 15 },
  { name: 'Steve', dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 20 },
  { name: 'Dan', dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020, pay: 30 }
];

function filter(arr, criterias) {
  let total = 0;
  criterias.forEach(criteria => {
    arr.forEach(obj => {
        if (Object.keys(criteria).every(c => obj[c] === criteria[c])) {
          total = total + obj.pay;
        }
    });
  });
   return total;
}

alert(filter(arr, [{ dateDay: 1, dateMonth: 1, dateYear: 2020 }, { dateDay: 2, dateMonth: 2, dateYear: 2020 }]));
```

Comment: It's a misuse of `filter()` to use it just for side effects like this. If you want to loop over `arr` you should use `forEach`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This does exactly what I need it to.

Comment: @MarkMeyer You're right. I copied his code without paying much attention to it and adjusted the use of the "every" function without looking at the bigger picture. My bad.